# What is the programming rationale for logic-less templates vs. more capabilities in the template language?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, mustache

What is the programming rationale of logic-less templates (as in mustache/handlebars)?  Why is purposely limiting the capabilities of the template language considered a good and desirable design pattern by the makers and users of these logic-less template libraries?

I've been working with node.js and handlebars lately on a small project and I find I'm regularly stymied by the lack of simple logic in handlebars templates.

Before I ditch the handlebars template engine in search of one that has greater logic capabilities, I'd like to understand the programming rationale behind using a logic-less template language.

I should clarify that I'm not asking for people's opinions on which kind of template language is better.  I'm asking what are the objective reasons that people designed, built and use logic-less templates.

---

Here's a fairly simple example of what I would like the template to be able to handle by itself, but I don't see how in handlebars so I don't understand why it's considered a desirable characteristic that the "logic-less" template can't handle such a simple UI presentation by itself.  Since there are a number of logic-less template choices, I am assuming there are useful reasons for it that I'd like to understand.

I have two variables from may app state that are passed to the template:

```
fanOn       // boolean: true or false
fanControl  // three states: "on", "off", "auto"
```

`fanOn` represents the current state on or off of some fans I am controlling
`fanControl` describes what kind of control mode the fans are in.  "on" means they are turned manually on and will stay that way until further notice.  "off" means they are turned manually off and will stay that way until further notice.  "auto" means they are under automatic thermostatic/software control.

If the fans are on, I want to display a button to manually turn them off.

If the fans are off, I want to display a button to manually turn them on.

If the fanControl setting is on or off, I want to display a button to set it back to auto.

So, there's always a "Turn On" or "Turn off" button and if it's not in "auto" mode, there's a "Set Back to Auto" button.

There's no business logic here, it's just a matter of building the proper presentation based on the current state.

Here are various references I've found on the topic (which contain a combination of opinion and fact - a reader has to sort out which is which):

- [Enforcing Strict Model-View Separation in Template Engines](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf)
- [What are the benefits of logic-less templates like {{Mustache}}?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-logic-less-templates-like-Mustache)
- [The Case Against Logic-Less Templates](http://pswar.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/the-case-against-logic-less-templates/)
- [Cult of Logic-less Templates](http://www.boronine.com/2012/09/07/Cult-Of-Logic-less-Templates/)
- [Logic-less Template Redux](http://jmoiron.net/blog/logicless-template-redux/)
- [Your templating engine sucks and everything you have ever written is spaghetti code (yes, you)](http://www.workingsoftware.com.au/page/Your_templating_engine_sucks_and_everything_you_have_ever_written_is_spaghetti_code_yes_you)
- [Simple is better - Template Engines](http://www.simple-is-better.org/template/)
- [Mustache is logic-less but the logic has to go somewhere](http://www.javarants.com/2013/03/09/mustache-is-logic-less-but-the-logic-has-to-go-somewhere/)
- [3 Reasons to choose Logic Less templates like Mustache](http://www.connecto.io/blog/3-reasons-to-choose-logic-less-templates-like-mustache/)
- [Dust is eloquent – the logic wars - Paypal Engineering Blog](https://www.paypal-engineering.com/tag/template/)

Comment: That's business logic: you have 2 UI displays, one when in auto mode, one when not in auto mode. The controller should chose between the two. It's not the view's job to choose. The view should just draw things to screen.

Comment: Note that if two templates share a lot of things with each other most templating engines have features that allow you to refactor them.

Comment: @slebetman - I consider it the template's job to decide how exactly to render the UI.  Should buttons be used, a radio group, a drop-down, etc...?  I see no reason why the javascript gathering the data that the page will represent needs to participate in whether it's buttons, a radio group or a drop-down list.  As far as I'm concerned, that is the job of the template to hold the appropriate design for that.  Yes Handlebars templates do have "partials" which contain reusable pieces of HTML usable in multiple places.  I am using them where appropriate-though I don't think that is relevant here.

Comment: Go read http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf for an excellent, academic treatment of why logic-less templating is a good thing. It all has to do with model-view separation.

Comment: @jfriend00: Read up on the MVC design pattern. MVC came from smalltalk and the veiw layer there wasn't templates but smalltalk code. Still the policy was to only call UI functions in the view and let the controller do all the decisions.

Comment: @jfriend00: In terms of express, the express app is the controller. You should have zero business logic in express. Only logic for linking together business logic and the view logic. All business logic should be your own modules written independent of any framework and database (the database is the persistence layer).

Comment: @ChrisTavares - thanks for the very relevant reference.  Good info.  The theory in that paper basically means that you must have code on the server that prepares data for the exact needs of the template.  If you change the template, you are likely to need to change view code on the server to make sure the data is prepared exactly the way the template can consume it unless you've anticipated everything.  It certainly would preclude any business logic being in the template, though it doesn't preclude business logic leaking into the view layer right above it or into client-side javascript.

Comment: I just want to neutrally point out that you ask for an explanation on a topic and then specify that you do not want people's opinions, but this, and any other consideration of management of complexity are all, without reservation, pure opinion. There is no science, no hard measurable fact behind the culture of software development and complexity management. All you can do is learn from the culture. I'd suggest you take the time to understand MVC before coming out bashing much of that culture as 'silly'. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @dwerner - I think you have the general idea.  Either way you have to have server-side code that knows where a given user is connected.  This way, all you need is a way for the client to directly connect to that location and then the game part is single server.

Comment: @dwerner - The article Chris linked to has all sorts of excellent data about issues that logic in templates can lead to and reasons to avoid that logic.  That's what I'm looking for in order to understand the programming benefits of such a design/architecture.  Selecting a tool for your own use will ultimately involve your own opinion about how you prioritize the capabilities,merits and tradeoffs vs. needs, but understanding the relative merits of each tool doesn't have to be all or even mostly opinion.  It can be mostly facts that one then forms their own opinion about.

Comment: Added a number of references to articles on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tendency, especially with inexperienced programmers, for people to include business logic in templates. This is generally considered bad practice and an anti-pattern. Business logic belongs in the model layer and should not have anything to do with presentation/view layer.

Taken to the extreme you'd end up with PHP - where 100% of all code, business logic, controller glue and views are embedded in HTML.

To discourage this, logicless templates were developed so that junior developers can't accidentally include business logic in the view layer easily.

For really good separation of concerns (single responsibility) checking for values in order to decide what to print on screen is not the responsibility of the view layer. It should be done in the controller. However, there are times when it really shouldn't be the job of the controller (when using compound UI elements made up of primitive elements for example, the checking may be part of the implementation detail). For those use cases it is often useful for templating libraries to provide workarounds such as helper methods. But such use cases should be rare.

If you keep having to write helper methods it may be you're just not used to separating controller logic from presentation logic. As such, some of the more extreme logicless templating languages such as Google's ctemplate doesn't even provide such workarounds (note that ctemplate predates a lot of the newer logicless templating languages).

Newer developments of logicless languages are even more extreme - templateless languages. Where the templating language has no language at all and you just pass the correct JSON data (or other structured data) and the templating engine will find the matching HTML elements with the correct id or class name to inject values into.

Comment: If you provided some code maybe someone could offer a cleaner solution to your problem.  What seem like limitations are the result of sound decisions made by people with a deep understanding of the underlying issues.

Comment: @PeterVC - I'm asking for an explanation of this deep understanding because allowing no useful decisions to be made in the presentation layer just seems far more limiting to me than it does helpful so I'm trying to understand why this group of people thinks differently.  That might also inform me how I should structure my code and why.  I will provide a specific example later today (heading out at the moment) - though I did describe one problem (at a high level) in my first comment to this post.

Comment: The misunderstanding stems from the (common) problem of conflating "template" with "presentation layer". Web frameworks and languages tend to do Views wrong :) A true MVC View isn't made out of a template file, it's made out of code. Mustache and other logic-less template engines enforce that distinction. Decisions _can't_ be made in a template. A template is simply a string populated by View code living elsewhere. If you come at it from that point of view the limitations of Mustache are workable. If instead of moving code to a View layer you try to do it without View code at all, it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterVC - I added a specific example to my question.

Comment: But those _are_ business logic. They're simple logic, but logic nonetheless. Your template would instead ask "should I show this button?" and "should I show that other button?" The logic required to make those decisions belongs in code, where it can be analyzed, and tested, and reasoned about. kneath touches on the power of this a bit here: http://warpspire.com/posts/mustache-style-erb/

Comment: @jfriend00: That's a good thing because it's easier to write a unit test for a pure function (the one that decides which template to use or what to pass to the template) than it is to unit test the template. Generally templates are extremely debug-unfriendly.

Comment: @bobthecow - They are presentation logic, not business logic.   Just like deciding what to do if the browser's window is really small instead of a big screen.  The business logic defines the operations that can be performed, carries out requested operations and reports state.  The business logic doesn't decide whether a page should use two buttons that change when you press one, a three-state radio group or a drop-down to show the different options.  Those are pure user interface decisions that have little to do with the actual business logic.

Answer (score 2):

After researching a bunch of other template languages, it appears that there are basically three schools of thought and you really have to decide which one lines up best with your development philosophy, team situation and project needs.

**Option #1:** Templates have a full-blown programming language in them (e.g. PHP).

**Option #2:** Templates are logic-less (e.g. Mustache/Handlebars).

**Option #3:** Templates have some capability to make presentation-focused logic decisions (e.g Dust).

The PHP model exists and works.  Without proper discipline, presentation and business logic can get very intertwined making an untestable mess.  This doesn't mean that good discipline and proper techniques can't lead to a clean implementation, but it is also easy to shoot one's self in the foot with improper practices.

Perhaps as a reaction to the mess that can be caused by this and some of the ensuing debate, the notion of logic-less templates arrived.  Zero business logic can ever get put into a logic-less template.  But, because there is no logic in the templates, there must be another layer of code somewhere that makes presentation logic decisions and preconditions the data sent to the template so that it perfectly aligns with the chosen UI design.  This requires a separate place for presentation logic code.  Without proper discipline or understanding, this code gets intermingled with the business logic and this code often has to be modified to make fairly simple changes to the UI design in the templates.  The undisciplined case is perhaps not as messy as with Option #1, but still some don't think this is ideal either - others seem to like it.

A third option is templates that attempt to expose enough logic to make presentation-based decisions based on screen size, based on state of the data, which radio button to select, which buttons to display, etc... but still keep that separate from any business logic in the main app.  Plus, this can allow a person of different skills (e.g. a UI designer) more complete control over the presentation without involving a javascript programmer from the main server-side app.

As with many tools, one can argue advantages and disadvantages of each approach and there are never absolute right or wrong answers.

In search of templates that were more in line with option #3, I came across [Dust](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#Logic_in_Templates) (used by LinkedIn) and [Walrus](https://github.com/jeremyruppel/walrus) and [Nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) with these blurbs in their documentation that helped describe their goal in relation to option #3:

From [Walrus](https://github.com/jeremyruppel/walrus):

*View logic is different than business logic (and that's okay!). In modern web apps, there's often a good amount of presentation logic involved. This logic doesn't belong in your application code, your backbone models, or anywhere else but the presentation layer. The templating language is a good place to put this.*

And, from [Dust](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#Logic_in_Templates):

*Logic in Templates*

*Templates with logic versus "logic-less" templates is a hotly debated point among template language designer and users. Dust straddles the divide by adopting a "less logic" stance. We all know that real business logic does not belong in the presentation layer, but what about simple presentation-oriented things like coloring alternate rows in table or marking the selected option in a  dropdown? It seems equally wrong to ask the controller/business logic code to compute these down to simple booleans in order to reduce the logic in the presentation template. This route just lead to polluting the business layer code with presentation-oriented logic.
Dust provides some simple logic mechanisms and trusts you to be sensible in minimizing the logic in your templates to only deal with presentation-oriented decisions. That said, let's take a look at the ways Dust let's you have logic.*